# Linking a Centos 7 Cluster

Tags: centos, networking, rhel, webserver, cluster

Five physical server boxes that each have Centos 7 installed will be joined in a cluster and will together host a web application. What is a best practice for physically linking the boxes together? Should Ethernet cables connect them each to some sort of router? If so, what kind of router? I have never done this before, so please elaborate starting with the basics.

Comment: How exactly will they become a cluster? You're putting this behind some load balancer hardware? Multiple IPs for the DNS name? Will you have some sort of session affinity, i.e. if I get served by box01 once, I will continue to get served by box01 for the next X minutes/hours? (In that case, maybe there's not much traffic between box01 and box02.) Do you create the cluster for performance increase or for added resiliency? (If you put everything behind the same router, everything goes down if your router fails.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I have never hooked up a group of physical boxes together before. So my question is basic. I.e. How do I physically connect the boxes so that the virtual machines that I create in each box can all be in the same virtual network as the virtual machines created in the other boxes. How do I physically hook this up? If it helps you to know i would use a Redis cluster for session management, then great, but I don;t want to lose the narrow focus of the question. Similarly, load balancers and multiple routers are possible future upgrades beyond the scope of this introductory question.